# Python script to open a file in Spotfire

Tags: python, ironpython, spotfire

So I want to add a button in my text area in Spotfire which will open an excel file (that is connected to my spotfire visualisation) or at least to a network folder with that file.

I believe I can write an ironpython script just to open that file and make changes. How will I do that? 
Update: 
After some googling I have tried to run a simple script smth like:

t=open('D:/data/folderA/folderB/file.xlsx','w')

To avoid problems with "/" or "\", I also tried importing os

import os
t=open('D:','data', 'folderA', 'folderB', 'file.xlsx', 'w')

Neither of these work.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

For those who is still struggling to find the solution, it turned out to be simpler than I thought it would.

`from System.Diagnostics import Process
Process.Start(r 'start c:\test\abc.xlsx')`